# What is the proper way to append to a path?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am accepting a path to a directory as a command line argument to one of my scripts. There are two things I want to do. The first is that I want to confirm that path passed in a directory. The second thing I want to do is append to the path with sub-directory names (I know the sub-directory names ahead of time). Are there any functions in the library that will automatically add a trailing `/` character to the path if it is missing, or must I check for this manually?

For instance, if `/User/local` is passed, then I must add `/bin` to the path, whereas I must add `bin` if the path `/User/local/` is passed.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Afaik `/User/local/bin` should be handled equal to `/User/local//bin` by the file system.

Comment: @Bergi Wow, that is really interesting. Thanks.

Comment: OK, since I got 4 upvotes on the comment it seems to be true :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you just want [path.join](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2), [fs.existsSync](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path), and [fs.statSync](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path)

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var dir = process.argv[2];

console.log(dir);
console.log(fs.existsSync(dir) && fs.statSync(dir).isDirectory());
console.log(path.join(dir, 'mysubdir'));
```

So if I run the above like: `node test.js /tmp` I will get:

```
/tmp
true
/tmp/mysubdir
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tail = 'bin/test/',
    path = arg[arg.length-1] === '/' ? arg + tail : arg + '/' + tail;
```

Or I missing something? :)

Comment: I have to append to a lot of paths in a lot of different places so I was hoping to avoid typing that hundreds of times. Doing so seems to be asking for a hidden typo bug. As Bergi pointed out, you don't even need to worry about the `/`.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You can write a function based on a code I wrote - it's simple. Why do you need libraries for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the logic into a short function that makes sure there is one and only one "/" between the two parts:

```
function appendToPath(orig, add) {
    return orig.replace(/\/$/, "") + "/" + add.replace(/^\//, "");
}

var newPath = appendToPath("/User/local", "bin");
```

or

```
var newPath = appendToPath("/User/local/", "/bin");
```

or

```
var newPath = appendToPath("/User/local", "/bin");
```

They all return `"/User/local/bin"`.